# JSOUP Login then Parse & Look for Price in HTML string

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, screen-scraping

I've got the program mostly figured out. I just need to pull the price from this HTML string: `<li class=""><b class="">Your Price:</b> $23.51&nbsp; &nbsp; <b class="">You Save:</b> $11.48</li>` I just need the "23.51" from that string, the one listed as Your Price.

I updated the code to reflect what I am currently working with. I'm not sure what the next step would be.

I don't know where to add in parse. I need it to take the URL from the spreadsheet then put the price data in the appropriate column (PRICE_COLUMN).

Here's my code, thanks to Krystian.

```
public class Scraper {


private static final int URL_COLUMN = 2; // Column C
private static final int SKU_COLUMN = 3; // Column D
private static final int SALE_COLUMN = 4;// Column E
private static final int PRICE_COLUMN = 5; //Column F

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    Workbook originalWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/original.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/updated.xls"), originalWorkbook);
    originalWorkbook.close();
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    int currentRow = 1;
    Cell cell;
    while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMN, currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {
        String url = cell.getContents();
        System.out.println("Parsing URL: " + url);
        String SKU = parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductSKU(url);
        String price = parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice(url);
        String sale= parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetSale(url);
        System.out.println("SKU: " + SKU);
        System.out.println("Regular price: " + price);
        System.out.println("Sale price: " + sale);
        Label cellWithSKU = new Label(SKU_COLUMN, currentRow, SKU);
        sheet.addCell(cellWithSKU);
        Label cellWithSale = new Label(SALE_COLUMN, currentRow, sale);
        sheet.addCell(cellWithSale);
        Label cellWithPrice = new Label(PRICE_COLUMN, currentRow, price);
        sheet.addCell(cellWithPrice);
        currentRow++;
    }
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();

}

private static String parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductSKU(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        return doc.select("#product_id_num").text();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
private static String parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetSale(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        return doc.select("#NA").text();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
private static String parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        System.out.println(getPrice(doc));
        return doc.select("#price").text();
        private static String price(Document doc) {
            // select all <li> inside <ul class="small">
            Elements liElements = doc.select("ul.small>li");
            for (Element li : liElements) {
                // find "List Price:"
                if (li.text().contains("List Price:")) {
                    // remove <b> with contents
                    li.select("b").remove();
                    // there's only price left in <li>
                    return li.text();
                }
            }
            return "not found";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more context to selected element? <li class=""> is not enough to select it.

Comment: <ul class="small"> <li class=""><b class="">Description:</b> ***. (Import)</li> <li class=""><b class="">List Price:</b> $*** EA</li> <li class=""><b class="">Your Price:</b> $***&nbsp; &nbsp; <b class="">You Save:</b> $***</li> <li class="stockStatus"><b class="">Stock Status:</b> 1</li> <h3 class="additionalInfo"><span class="">Additional Information</span></h3> <li class="additional">Uses extension part# ***</li> <li class="additional">Replaces GM# ***</li> </ul>

Comment: Krystian, should we filter by certain string? Or how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation in comments:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .parse("<ul class=\"small\">    <li class=\"\"><b class=\"\">Description:</b> . (Import)</li> <li class=\"\"><b class=\"\">List Price:</b> $123</li> <li class=\"\"><b class=\"\">Your Price:</b> $***&nbsp; &nbsp; <b class=\"\">You Save:</b> $***</li> <li class=\"stockStatus\"><b class=\"\">Stock Status:</b> 1</li> <h3 class=\"additionalInfo\"><span class=\"\">Additional Information</span></h3> <li class=\"additional\">Uses extension part# ***</li> <li class=\"additional\">Replaces GM# ***</li> </ul> ");
    System.out.println(getPrice(doc));
}

private static String getPrice(Document doc) {
    // select all <li> inside <ul class="small">
    Elements liElements = doc.select("ul.small>li");
    for (Element li : liElements) {
        // find "List Price:"
        if (li.text().contains("List Price:")) {
            // remove <b> with contents
            li.select("b").remove();
            // there's only price left in <li>
            return li.text();
        }
    }
    return "not found";
}
```

Comment: Error:(47, 19) java: class, interface, or enum expected
I'm getting errors on the new lines, starting with "void". I'm attempting to figure it out right now

Comment: Something I'm wondering if this can do is still output into the spreadsheet "update". It looks like this code does not utilize the URL, so I simply added it to the previous code, but of course I'm getting the error that main string is already defined.

Comment: This is a standalone example of how to get the price from `Document` (your HTML code) so everyone can run it without using your previous code. You don't need url because you already have downloaded and parsed the page into `doc` object. You should use this code inside `parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice(url)` method.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with this. So are you saying when I run the program, it's downloaded? I need it to fetch new strings for every URL it visits, but the string format will be the exact same. The prices will change however. I can't see where to implement this in my code, it's still saying a lot of things aren't defined even when I try to put it in "parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice"

Comment: In other words, it's going through our spreadsheet of links, and it needs to pull the strings but filter them (or parse?) before returning the price data to the sheet. Edit: Updated code posted